# How to add gridster item on a grid using a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, gridster

So, I'm using the Gridster-Angular directive (https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster), and I have a grid with three boxes on my view:

```
<div gridster="gridsterOpts">
    <ul id="gridster-ul">
        <li gridster-item id="box1" row="0" col="0" size-x="3" size-y="2"></li>

        <li gridster-item id="box2" row="0" col="3" size-x="3" size-y="2"></li>

        <li gridster-item id="box3" row="3" col="0" size-x="6" size-y="1"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then I have a button in which I call the `addWidget()` function, in order to add a new box to the `ul`:

```
<div id="right-panel" class="panel">
    <h2 id="panel-title">Visualizations</h2>
            <a class="btn btn-primary center-block" id="add-item-button" ng-click="addWidget()">Add Item</a>
</div>
```

The function in my `controller`:

```
$scope.addWidget = function() {
        console.log("add1");
        $("#gridster-ul").addClass('gridster-item');
    }
```

The console gives no errors whatsoever. The problem is that it doesn't add the new `item`. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend to use [`gridStack`](https://github.com/Tropicalista/angular-gridstack) instead

Comment: I think that solution still causes the same problem...

Comment: Maybe I did not quite understand you. Where you add an item? I see only add class `gridster-item`.

Comment: Well, that is the problem, I don't know how to add